# PHP HTML forms that retain data entered and isset()

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having trouble with my current code below. I am trying to retain the user entered information that is input into the a and b data boxes using PHP_SELF but this does not happen. I think I may have to have some kind of POST statement made in the HTML code, but I'm not sure. Also, I am trying to use isset() to determine if BOTH fields are being entered, and it doesnt seem to be working as die() is being called every time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



 <html>

 <body>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

 <table align="center" border="0">
  <tr>
 <td>a:</td>
 <td ><input type="text" VALUE="<?php $a ?>" name="a" size="6" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>b:</td>
 <td ><input type="text" VALUE="<?php $b ?>" name="b" size="10" maxlength="10"></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 </form>

 <?php 
if(isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])){


 $a = $_POST['a'];
 $b = $_POST['b'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE $a = DATA1 $b = DATA2";


 $name= mysql_query($query) or die();

 echo '<table border = 1>';

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($name)) 
 {
echo '<tr>';
foreach($row as $cvalue) {
    print '<td>'.$cvalue.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';


}



?>
```

Comment: you use $a before you assing $_POST['a'] to it

Comment: "does not seem to work" is very vague. Try to narrow it down using basic debugging methods

Comment: are u sure SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE $a = DATA1 $b = DATA2 is correct or it should be as SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE DATA1 = '$a' AND DATA2 = '$b' ?

Comment: by "does not work" I mean that die() is being called every time, and error messages are not displayed if only one form has information in it

Comment: @You should see my answer below. It might help you out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go through your code and see what I find. No promises. I might not find the problem, but I might help in other ways.

```
  <tr>
 <td>a:</td>
 <td ><input type="text" VALUE="<?php $a ?>" name="a" size="6" maxlength="6" /></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>b:</td>
 <td ><input type="text" VALUE="<?php $b ?>" name="b" size="10" maxlength="10" /></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" /></td>
  </tr>
```

You should self close your input tags (brings you closer to XHTML standards). Also, the PHP in the `<input>` controls is malformed. The statements should read something like this:

```
<td ><input type="text" VALUE="<?php echo Sa; ?>" name="a" size="6" maxlength="6" /></td>  // echo() statements!
<td ><input type="text" VALUE="<?php echo Sb; ?>" name="a" size="6" maxlength="6" /></td>
<td ><input type="text" VALUE="<?php echo Sc; ?>" name="a" size="6" maxlength="6" /></td>

<?php  if(isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])){
```

Or, if you only want to make one call to isset()

```
 <?php 

if(isset($_POST['a'], $_POST['b'])){
```

[PHP Manual: isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
 $query = "SELECT * 
             FROM DATA 
            WHERE $a  = 'DATA1' AND $b = 'DATA2'";
```

Make sure your query string is quoted properly if fields $a and $b refer to string values.
However, since $a and $b are what the user entered, I believe your is a bit backwards.

```
 $query = "SELECT * 
             FROM DATA 
            WHERE DATA1 = '$a' 
              AND DATA2 = '$b'";
```

Ah, now that makes more sense. If the DATA1 and DATA2 fields refer to integers (int values), the query would look like this

$query = "SELECT *
FROM DATA
WHERE DATA1 = $a
AND DATA2 = $b";

As for the following code snippet ... you are not using $cvalue as an associative array.
[PHP Manual: mysql_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

If you only want the values (and not the keys and values), you might use [mysql_fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($name)) 
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cvalue) 
    {
        print '<td>'.$cvalue.'</td>';
    }
}

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

... this might work a bit better for you.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($name)) 
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cvalue) //Now you are cooking with gas.
    {
        echo '<td>'.$cvalue.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Give mysqli functions a chance if you have time to change your code. [PHP Manual: MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php)

Hope that was not too brutal. Just trying to help. :-)